# Consumo web service con PHP

Tags: php, webservice

Buen Dia,
Programe el consumo de un web service con php y en mi ambiente de pruebas funciona correctamente, pero al pasar a produccion el servidor me genera un error 500

> **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)**

y me genera error en el AJAX

> f.send(a.hasContent&&a.data||null),b=function(c,e){var h,i,j;if(b&&(e||4===f.readyState))if(delete Xc[g],b=void 0,f.onreadystatechange=m.noop,e)4!==f.readyState&&f.abort();else{j={},h=f.status,"string"==typeof f.responseText&&(j.text=f.responseText);try{i=f.statusText}catch(k){i=""}h||!a.isLocal||a.crossDomain?1223===h&&(h=204):h=j.text?200:404}j&&d(h,i,j,f.getAllResponseHeaders())},a.async?4===f.readyState?setTimeout(b):f.onreadystatechange=Xc[g]=b:b()},abort:function(){b&&b(void 0,!0)}}}});function Zc(){try{return new a.XMLHttpRequest}catch(b){}}function $c(){try{return new a.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")}catch(b){}}m.ajaxSetup({accepts:{script:"text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript"},contents:{script:/(?:java|ecma)script/},converters:{"text script":function(a){return m.globalEval(a),a}}}),m.ajaxPrefilter("script",function(a){void 0===a.cache&&(a.cache=!1),a.crossDomain&&(a.type="GET",a.global=!1)}),m.ajaxTransport("script",function(a){if(a.crossDomain){var b,c=y.head||m("head")[0]||y.documentElement;return{send:function(d,e){b=y.createElement("script"),b.async=!0,a.scriptCharset&&(b.charset=a.scriptCharset),b.src=a.url,b.onload=b.onreadystatechange=function(a,c){(c||!b.readyState||/loaded|complete/.test(b.readyState))&&(b.onload=b.onreadystatechange=null,b.parentNode&&b.parentNode.removeChild(b),b=null,c||e(200,"success"))},c.insertBefore(b,c.firstChild)},abort:function(){b&&b.onload(void 0,!0)}}}});var _c=[],ad=/(=)\?(?=&|$)|\?\?/;m.ajaxSetup({jsonp:"callback",jsonpCallback:function(){var a=*c.pop()||m.expando+"*"+vc++;return this[a]=!0,a}}),m.ajaxPrefilter("json jsonp",function(b,c,d){var e,f,g,h=b.jsonp!==!1&&(ad.test(b.url)?"url":"string"==typeof b.data&&!(b.contentType||"").indexOf("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")&&ad.test(b.data)&&"data");return h||"jsonp"===b.dataTypes[0]?(e=b.jsonpCallback=m.isFunction(b.jsonpCallback)?b.jsonpCallback():b.jsonpCallback,h?b[h]=b[h].replace(ad,"$1"+e):b.jsonp!==!1&&(b.url+=(wc.test(b.url)?"&":"?")+b.jsonp+"="+e),b.converters["script json"]=function(){return g||m.error(e+" was not called"),g[0]},b.dataTypes[0]="json",f=a[e],a[e]=function(){g=arguments},d.always(function(){a[e]=f,b[e]&&(b.jsonpCallback=c.jsonpCallback,_c.push(e)),g&&m.isFunction(f)&&f(g[0]),g=f=void 0}),"script"):void 0}),m.parseHTML=function(a,b,c){if(!a||"string"!=typeof a)return null;"boolean"==typeof b&&(c=b,b=!1),b=b||y;var d=u.exec(a),e=!c&&[];return d?[b.createElement(d[1])]:(d=m.buildFragment([a],b,e),e&&e.length&&m(e).remove(),m.merge([],d.childNodes))};var bd=m.fn.load;m.fn.load=function(a,b,c){if("string"!=typeof a&&bd)return bd.apply(this,arguments);var d,e,f,g=this,h=a.indexOf(" ");return h>=0&&(d=m.trim(a.slice(h,a.length)),a=a.slice(0,h)),m.isFunction(b)?(c=b,b=void 0):b&&"object"==typeof b&&(f="POST"),g.length>0&&m.ajax({url:a,type:f,dataType:"html",data:b}).done(function(a){e=arguments,g.html(d?m("").append(m.parseHTML(a)).find(d):a)}).complete(c&&function(a,b){g.each(c,e||[a.responseText,b,a])}),this},m.expr.filters.animated=function(a){return m.grep(m.timers,function(b){return a===b.elem}).length};var cd=a.document.documentElement;function dd(a){return m.isWindow(a)?a:9===a.nodeType?a.defaultView||a.parentWindow:!1}m.offset={setOffset:function(a,b,c){var d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k=m.css(a,"position"),l=m(a),n={};"static"===k&&(a.style.position="relative"),h=l.offset(),f=m.css(a,"top"),i=m.css(a,"left"),j=("absolute"===k||"fixed"===k)&&m.inArray("auto",[f,i])>-1,j?(d=l.position(),g=d.top,e=d.left):(g=parseFloat(f)||0,e=parseFloat(i)||0),m.isFunction(b)&&(b=b.call(a,c,h)),null!=b.top&&(n.top=b.top-h.top+g),null!=b.left&&(n.left=b.left-h.left+e),"using"in b?b.using.call(a,n):l.css(n)}},m.fn.extend({offset:function(a){if(arguments.length)return void 0===a?this:this.each(function(b){m.offset.setOffset(this,a,b)});var b,c,d={top:0,left:0},e=this[0],f=e&&e.ownerDocument;if(f)return b=f.documentElement,m.contains(b,e)?(typeof e.getBoundingClientRect!==K&&(d=e.getBoundingClientRect()),c=dd(f),{top:d.top+(c.pageYOffset||b.scrollTop)-(b.clientTop||0),left:d.left+(c.pageXOffset||b.scrollLeft)-(b.clientLeft||0)}):d},position:function(){if(this[0]){var a,b,c={top:0,left:0},d=this[0];return"fixed"===m.css(d,"position")?b=d.getBoundingClientRect():(a=this.offsetParent(),b=this.offset(),m.nodeName(a[0],"html")||(c=a.offset()),c.top+=m.css(a[0],"borderTopWidth",!0),c.left+=m.css(a[0],"borderLeftWidth",!0)),{top:b.top-c.top-m.css(d,"marginTop",!0),left:b.left-c.left-m.css(d,"marginLeft",!0)}}},offsetParent:function(){return this.map(function(){var a=this.offsetParent||cd;while(a&&!m.nodeName(a,"html")&&"static"===m.css(a,"position"))a=a.offsetParent;return a||cd})}}),m.each({scrollLeft:"pageXOffset",scrollTop:"pageYOffset"},function(a,b){var c=/Y/.test(b);m.fn[a]=function(d){return V(this,function(a,d,e){var f=dd(a);return void 0===e?f?b in f?f[b]:f.document.documentElement[d]:a[d]:void(f?f.scrollTo(c?m(f).scrollLeft():e,c?e:m(f).scrollTop()):a[d]=e)},a,d,arguments.length,null)}}),m.each(["top","left"],function(a,b){m.cssHooks[b]=Lb(k.pixelPosition,function(a,c){return c?(c=Jb(a,b),Hb.test(c)?m(a).position()[b]+"px":c):void 0})}),m.each({Height:"height",Width:"width"},function(a,b){m.each({padding:"inner"+a,content:b,"":"outer"+a},function(c,d){m.fn[d]=function(d,e){var f=arguments.length&&(c||"boolean"!=typeof d),g=c||(d===!0||e===!0?"margin":"border");return V(this,function(b,c,d){var e;return m.isWindow(b)?b.document.documentElement["client"+a]:9===b.nodeType?(e=b.documentElement,Math.max(b.body["scroll"+a],e["scroll"+a],b.body["offset"+a],e["offset"+a],e["client"+a])):void 0===d?m.css(b,c,g):m.style(b,c,d,g)},b,f?d:void 0,f,null)}})}),m.fn.size=function(){return this.length},m.fn.andSelf=m.fn.addBack,"function"==typeof define&&define.amd&&define("jquery",[],function(){return m});var ed=a.jQuery,fd=a.$;return m.noConflict=function(b){return a.$===m&&(a.$=fd),b&&a.jQuery===m&&(a.jQuery=ed),m},typeof b===K&&(a.jQuery=a.$=m),m});

Esta igual que en desarrollo, le apuntan al mismo webmethod.

Gracias

Comment: Los errores 500 son de servidor, no de Ajax, así que poco podemos hacer con lo que muestras en la pregunta. Con que hayas omitido una coma o puesto algo de más en el código PHP te dará error 500. Revisa de nuevo el código en el servidor, haz pruebas sencillas si fuera preciso, como enviar algo y devolver un mensaje simple. Y luego ve depurando más profundamente.

Answer (score 1):

Un código de respuesta 500 por parte del servidor implica que hubo una situación no controlada (como excepción o error) y por lo tanto no hay una respuesta satisfactoria(https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:C%C3%B3digos_de_estado_HTTP).

En este caso se debe contactar al proveedor del servicio para que se estudie el error.